# Can test written on PyTest calculate the code coverage using Jacoco of Java code?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, test-coverage, jacoco-plugin

We have a test automation framework using pytest and the codebase of the mobile applications is in Java.

Currently the dev team is running their unit and Integration tests using Junit and generates the Code coverage reports using the JaCoCo.

We want to write our unit and integration tests using pytest, and generate test coverage report using JaCoCo for the java codebase.

How is this possible ?